# Meta-analysis of three glm models (binomial) with correlation coefficient

Tags: r, glm, meta-analysis

I have ran three simple logistic regression models:
glm( factor(response) ~ factor(sex) + age + gene expression,
data = data_2, family = binomial

Now I have for all three models the Coefficient Estimate, Std. Error, z value and p-value obtained via summary(model).

Now I would like to combine all three studies via a meta-analysis, preferably using these results I obtained.

Could you guide me on how to do this.. Is it possible and if so, how could I do this?

Thank you,
Bine

Comment: This is more of a statistical question than a programming one. If you need help with what type of statistical analysis to perform, you should ask your question over at [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com). I have voted to migrate your question over there.

Comment: okay, I will post it there. Thank you.